# How is my array that I am not using getting updated?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my function:

```
function RemoveOutputKeys(array){
  var temp = array;
  for(var object in temp){
    delete temp[object]['statusCode']
    delete temp[object]['statusResponse']
  } 
  console.log(array)
  if(temp == array)
    console.log("how is this possible?!?!!?!?!")
  return temp
}
```

and here is the input I am providing,

```
array = [{'statusCode':400},{'statusCode':200}]
```

It makes sense for `temp` to get updated but I don't want the `array` to get updated. How can i fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: `var temp = array;` doesn't make a new array. You're still working on `array`.

Comment: Don't use `for(... in...)` to iterate arrays

Comment: Also, `if(temp == array)` is an object identity comparison, not a value comparison.

Comment: Your `temp` variable just **points** to your array, it is done through a reference.

Comment: I see! Never knew that

Comment: Why is for(...in...) bad for iterating?

Comment: Ill gogle that above comment^ Dw about it

Comment: @J.Doe basically, `for...in` is bad, because it iterates over _object properties_, so it can behave oddly with arrays. In older browsers, it also iterated over stuff like `.length` and `.indexOf()`, for example. You can see more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea). You can use the newer [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or a normal `for` loop to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want create new array instead of alias/reference use:

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Array.prototype.filter()** instead of **for in**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
function RemoveOutputKeys(array) {
  return array.filter(function(myArray) {
      if (!myArray['statusCode'] && !myArray['statusResponse']) {
          return myArray;
      }
  });
}

var originalArray = [{'statusCode':400}, {'statusCode':200}, {'test': 'test'}];

var tempArray = RemoveOutputKeys(originalArray);

console.log(originalArray, tempArray);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3kbypvcs/2/